# Running listener in background without freezing gui C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I recently started exploring networking using Sockets in C# and I noticed that while the server listens for the connection the gui freezes. I was wondering if there is an easy workaround for that? 
When we are at that, I also wanted to ask about handling multiple clients.
Should I have one listener and a list(or similar) of sockets to handle connected clients? 
If I should have one listener then how should I go about accepting multiple connections with only one listener?

Please keep in mind I am quite new when it comes to C#.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use Tasks/Threads etc.

Comment: As @Eser notes use Tasks, but more specifically the async/await support built into .NET which makes working with concurrent and asynchronous operations far easier.

Comment: You need to run the listening part on another thread. One easy way is using the `BackgroundWorker`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my UI not Freeze while background code is running C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634372/how-do-i-make-my-ui-not-freeze-while-background-code-is-running-c-sharp)

Answer (score -2):

If you are working on a windows application, use `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Any explanation or a brief demo would improve this answer.